# PHP: Show content at certain time

Tags: php, wordpress

New to PHP and wordpress.

I'm trying to show different content at certain times (BST).

e.g Breakfast content: 8am, Lunch content 1pm

**How would I go about creating a if loop to show content based on the current time?**

Below is the content for breakfast.

```
<?php

$rows = get_field('breakfast');
$row_count = count($rows);
$i = rand(0, $row_count - 1);

?>

<h1>
<?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_name']; ?>
</h1>
<p>
<?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_description'];  ?>
</p>
<h3>
Served<span><?php echo $rows[ $i ]['time_served'];  ?></span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? (With `date` that is..)

Comment: Thanks. Following the examples on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php now

Comment: This can be helpful too: http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-dates-and-times/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it. If this can be done any better please do let me know.

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('BST');
 $currentTime = time();
 $breakfast = strtotime("11:30 am");
?>

<?php if ($currentTime > $breakfast): ?>
        <h1>
            <?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_name']; ?>
        </h1>
        <p>
           <?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_description'];  ?>
        </p>
        <h3>
            Served<span><?php echo $rows[ $i ]['time_served'];  ?></span>
        </h3>
    }
<?php endif; ?>
```